# How to add an Existing Java Project to Git repository

Tags: java, linux, git, github

I am trying to add an existing Java project from a workspace to my git repository.

I'm using git version 1.8.3.2 on Linux.

I use this command:

```
git init/committed/remote origin/pushed
```

However, the src directory is only appearing as a greyed out empty folder.

How do I add a folder with subfolders to my github repository?

This is what it looks like.  Notice 'src' is greyed out and un-clickable.

[image]

Comment: After `git init`, did you add everything to the repo? (`git add .`?)

Comment: Yep, I did, I can see everything on the "master-branch" but I can't submerge and explore the folders because they're grayed-out and isn't clickable.

Comment: `bin` and `src` appear to be sub-repositories, not part of the same git repository. Is this what you intend?

Comment: Look [here](https://github.com/Codesane/Simple-Chat-Application/commit/4635d0b2c11ae9d791af4afc091256882fdfad0c) at `src` and `bin`. They say "subproject commit". Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124483/difference-between-subprojects-and-submodules-in-git), [this](http://longair.net/blog/2010/06/02/git-submodules-explained/) and [the pro-git book](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-6.html) to understand what a submodule is. It's not browsable because those directories are other git repositories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`src` and `bin` are `git submodules`. They're not browsable because they are only pointers to other git repositories - they're not really "folders".

To add everything in a directory and subdirectories to git in one command, you can use `git add .`, which [recursively adds](http://gitref.org/basic/).

[Section 6 of the Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-6.html) explains what a submodule is.

Assuming you do not want submodules, you can fix your repository like this:

```
cd <project> # Go to the projects root
rm -rf .git  # Remove all git information (keeping your code). 
cd src       # and repeat for src and bin
rm -rf .git
cd ../bin
rm -rf .git
cd ..        # now, back in the projects root
git init     # Make a git repository
git add .    # Add everything to it
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
git remote add github <github-url>
git push -f github # Force push to github, to overwrite everything we had before.
```

#### Note that this will destroy the git repos in `src` and `bin`!!

I'm *pretty* sure this is what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

To add `*.*` files and folders do it as follow:

1. Navigate within your terminal/dos window to the the root folder of your project and use the command:

> **git init**
>
> **git add .**
>
> **git commit -m "This is my commit"**
>
> **git push origin master**

BTW: you can find more simplified details in the following tutorial:
**[Import an existing, unversioned code project to an empty repository](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Import+code+from+an+existing+project)**

Comment: For some reason it feels like I did just that when I followed the other guys instructions, and for some reason his worker instead of this one. Thanks for your input though!

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this guide: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/